# Como informar ao usuário que o valor digitado é inválido?

Tags: python, string, conversão-de-tipo, int, cast

Suponhamos que seja pedido ao usuário que ele digite um número inteiro e este valor será guardado em uma variável. Há algumas formas de fazer isto, exponho as duas que consigo (com meu conhecimento básico) imaginar:

```
 n1 = int(input("Digite um valor inteiro:\n"))
```

Ou

```
 n1 = input("Digite um valor inteiro:\n")
 num1 = int(n1)
```

Nas duas ocasiões eu faço um cast e o valor torna-se inteiro. Até ai okay.

A questão é: se o usuário digitar um valor como 2.5, como posso fazer para que não de erro no programa e seja informado para ele que o valor deve ser um inteiro?

Comment: Poderia ser algo [assim](https://ideone.com/LqP9w4). A resposta abaixo tem alguns problemas: se digitar `0` (zero) o programa entra em loop, sem contar o fato de converter para `int` duas vezes (uma para verificar, outra depois para usar a variável), sendo que faz mais sentido fazer a conversão apenas uma vez. Sem contar o `input` dentro do `except` (que de certa forma viola o DRY) e o uso desnecessário de `pass`

Answer (score -3):

Use o método de string "isdigit" para fazer a verficação antes do casting. "isdigit" retorna True caso todos os elementos da string são números ([0-9]) e a string não esteja vazia, caso contrário retornará False. Ex.:

```
while True:
    numStr = input('Digite um valor inteiro: ')
    if numStr.isdigit(): # Verifica se todos elementos da string são números, a string deve conter no mínimo 1 caracter
        # Neste bloco podes podes fazer o cast de numStr para int
        print('É um número')
    else:
        # Fazer o cast de numStr para int neste bloco resultará em erro
        print('Não é um número')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Ola,

Para essa solução basta usar o Try except, quando for gerado um erro ele irá para o except onde você tratara o erro, no caso abaixo, eu criei um while que solicita para ele entrar com o valor correte, e essa repetição ocorre até que ele coloque um numero inteiro

```
n1 = input('Digite o valor inteiro ')
while 1:
    try:
        if(int(n1)):
            break
    except:
        n1 = input('Ops o valor deve ser inteiro, digite novamente ')
        pass

n2 = input('Digite o segundo valor inteiro ')
while 1:
    try:
        if(int(n2)):
            break
    except:
        n2 = input('Ops o valor deve ser inteiro, digite novamente ')
        pass


print(int(n1) + int(n2))
```

Comment: Teste digitando `0` (zero), o programa entra em loop...